Use some kind of helper function In EF Select query to make subquery
I have several tables that handles different kinds of translations for my entities and those tables to linked via relations to other entities.
I use subquery to directly access translations tables which is fine. This subquery is pretty similar in each case and takes several lines of code that I ideally want to move to some kind of helper.
So, this is samples of my typical ef queries:
This works fine, but as you can see, the translation part took some space that I wan't to get rid of:
var items = await _context.Users
    .Select(x => new UserModel()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        FirstName = x.FirstName,
        ...,
        Type = _context.StaticTranslations
           .Where(st => st.Key == x.TypeNameKey && st.LanguageId == 2)
           .OrderByDescending(st => st.Version)
           .Select(st => st.Value)
           .FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
    })
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

I tried to do this:
Type = _context.StaticTranslation(x.TypeNameKey, 2)

Where StaticTranslation is a static class with this method:
public static string StaticTranslation(this DbContextHandler context, string key, int languageId)
{
    return context.StaticTranslations
        .Where(st => st.Key == key && st.LanguageId == languageId)
        .OrderByDescending(st => st.Version)
        .Select(st => st.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
}

But with this solution, the EF trying to evaluate this subquery separately (or sees this as different calls, i'm not sure) and throws an error like:
"The LINQ expression could not be translated...."
I tried also to rewrite this helper to return "IQueriable" instead of "string" and to mode "FirstOrDefault" outside, but the issue is the same.
Anybody have any ideas how to tell EF not to try to translate that subqueries and consider them as part of same single query?

I think you'd need a thrid party library like LinqKit and pass it an Expression<Func<string, int, string>>
